# jQuery remove() not removing on first attempt even though the element to be removed is visible at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have an ajax call with async set to false to load content into a particular div. Among this content there is a button with id='cancelbtn. Problem is, if I call remove, it is not removed, even though the console prints the element correctly one line before. Weirdly, if I repeat the remove line a number of times, then it works 'as expected'. Any ideas? The code from the ajax call is:

```
    $.ajax ({
    url: 'contentincludingthecancelbtn.html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#divCont').html(data); 
        console.log($('#cancelbtn'));
        $('#cancelbtn').remove();
    });
    });
```

The button displays at the end. This used to be a direct load call (not working either) changed in order to try async:false but no luck.

Comment: one question, do you have just one id with cancelbtn? Do you check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have two elements with the same ID, so the jQuery is removing the first one and then the second (the one  you want to remove).

To solve this you could change the element's ID or try this code:

```
$('#divCont').find('#cancelbtn').remove();
```

Comment: i thought so... but then printed all elements with the id and there is only the one. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: If that's what's happening, you should probably change your document to eliminate the duplicate id, rather than working around it.

Comment: have also tried the find approach... actually i re-edited the code back from it to post the question here

Comment: oh god... i'm sorry for waisting your time.. and you are absolutely right... it's duplicated and had escaped me earlier... Thanks so much to the both of you, and mr Peruggia aka Johnny Bravo can have his "selected answer" as a reward!

Answer (score 1):

try to remove button on complete event
like this:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'contentincludingthecancelbtn.html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#divCont').html(data); 
        console.log($('#cancelbtn'));
        },
    complete: function(){
        $('#cancelbtn').remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks... it was my bad...  had repeated element id.

Comment: still, do any Dom operation on the data received via ajax in complete event handler, if your data is huge or network is slow, it will break if you tried to change it in success handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should be **careful** when using ids because they are supposed to be **unique** 
so we don't have **two elements** with the **same id** 
even when we have two elements with the same id for example

```
$('body').append('<p id="para">text</p><p id="para">text</p>');
```

now the following code :

```
$('#para').click(function(){console.log('just clicked ');});
```

will work just for the first element which is the first paragraph

**note :** 
`$('#divCont').find('#cancelbtn').remove()` : is good to make sure that we deleted all the elements with the id divCont 
**but** 
in the other hand it doesn't make sense because **.find** jquery method is used when we expect the matched elements to be greater than 1 **while** we know that ids should be unique so **$('#divCont').remove();** is enough